# Is there a way to track how many users open your app(hourly,daily,etc)?

Tags: android, statistics

So does anyone know if there is a program that will allow me to track how many times my app is opened daily?

I'm not looking to track the users behavior or anything, I just what stats on the average use of my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know this you need to send information to a server somehow. On the device you would need some kind of library or code that posts this information. On the server you need some service that receives it.

There's a number of tools that let you do that. Analytics tools for example: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/

If you don't want to use a pre-made tool you could simply use an HttpClient and you could make a simple Servlet on the server that dumps the use count into a database.

Tow more details:
1- Make sure you ask the user for permission the first time he runs your app. This could be problematic for him because of privacy and bandwith.
2- I would batch this and send it to the server once per day (midnight).

I hope this helps.
Emmanuel

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you should ask the user for permission to upload this kind of data!

Answer (score 0):

If want something easy to implement, you can use http://www.localytics.com/ I've used it for a couple of apps and it works really well.